# Rain Got To Untreated Wood Furniture Project - What to Do?

Tags: wood, lumber, rain, stain, wet

I've been building a bedframe from unfinished wood on my deck (due to lack of indoor workspace), and tarping it off at night to protect it. Apparently I did a poor job last night though, as the wind blew a corner of the tarp off, said corner taking a few minutes of rain today.

My question is basically - what should I do now? I was planning on doing some sanding and bolting tonight, and staining later this week. Is there a general guideline for how long it takes untreated wood to dry out enough for either of those purposes, and should I be worried about warping once it dries?

Very mad at myself, and been having trouble finding answers to these particular questions - thanks much.

Edit: Also, should I be worried about the water damaging/staining the wood's appearance?

Comment: let the wood dry slowly and completely. I don't think it will effect the final appearance once you have finished and sanded it. BTW what type of wood?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunataly there's very little to do but wait and see.  Whether it warps or discolors or both will be revealed in the next 2 or three days.

Answer (score 1):

What is going to happen is the wood grain will be "raised". All this means is the fibers that make up that particular section of wood that got wet will swell from re-hydrating. If you happen to be in the sanding stage of your project you will be relieved to know that many woodworkers purposely moisten their unfinished wood. When the wood dries the grain is left higher then before and when sanded produces a smoother glossier grain. If the wood is damp let it sit to dry inside at room temperature. If it was saturated, wipe dry with a clean towel and also move to a warm area to dry slowly. If the wood dries to quickly it may split, check, warp, etc. you get the idea.